# How to show icon to small opened web page title

Tags: html

I have added icon to small web page but when web page is opened, in address bar, icon is not displayed.

```
<head>
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="document_graph.ico" sizes="128x128" />
</head>
```

Main web page:

```
        <div class="button" id="Edit" align="right" name="Edit" value="PopupCenter" onclick="PopupCenter('http://localhost/chart.php','xtf','1000','600');">Show Performance Comparison</div>
```

Right now, no icon is displayed when small web page is opened after hit button but if opened small web page with address copy-paste, it is displayed in IE but not in Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be working

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="document_graph.ico" type="image/x-icon">
```

Comment: Thank, it's working for Chrome but in IE and Mozilla, icon is still not displayed. If opened, after adding address in bar, icon is displayed in all 3 browsers. But seems still something wrong for IE and Mozilla. Used below simple page to check: '<html>
<head>
  <title>Performance Records Comparison</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="document_graph.ico" type="image/x-icon">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
</head>
</html>'

Comment: I tried clearing cache but same issue, i displayed page in new tab instead of floating it (which was not the case earlier). In this case, icon is displayed.

Answer (score 1):

The mimetype of the .ico is not "image/png", but instead "image/x-icon".  (This is actually debated, but "image/x-icon" should work.)

Answer (score 1):

you need to check your image then. try creating a favicon here http://favicon.htmlkit.com/favicon/ and replace your image with the one generated here. Do clear your cache.